# R 'Splashr' - error on Windows

Tags: python, r, splash-js-render

I'm trying to get the R package "Splashr" working following [this tutorial](https://rud.is/b/2017/02/09/diving-into-dynamic-website-content-with-splashr/).

Ive installed [Docker for windows](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) successfully, [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and (hopefully) the dependent Python packages. I've set the path for Python in System Variables and tried this R code with both Python 2.7 and 3.6 but get the same error:

```
library(splashr)    
install_splash()

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Unexpected OS error "The handle is invalid", errno=9',)

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\docker\api\image.py", line 381, in pull
    header = auth.get_config_header(self, registry)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 50, in get_config_header
    authcfg = resolve_authconfig(client._auth_configs, registry)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 97, in resolve_authconfig
    authconfig, registry, store_name
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 142, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
    'Credentials store error: {0}'.format(repr(e))
```

I'm using Windows 10 Pro Version 1703

R version 3.4.3

R Studio Version 1.1.383

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you file an issue? https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr/issues as I may be able to give you a Windows cmdline workaround there (back-and-forth comments here are ugh & this might take a few rounds of trying things.)

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr, I've done that, much obliged. https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr/issues/11